# can I turn off zoom resolution in openlayers 3 drag zoom

Tags: openlayers, zoom

Using an openlayers 3 map. I want to do drag zoom to in-between resolutions rather than to the nearest integer zoom.  I can see that pinchzoom has a constrainResolution but there doesn't seem to be anything on dragzoom. Openlayers 2 seemed to have a fractionalzoom that did what I want, can I get the same effect in openlayers 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you upgrade to OpenLayers >= v3.20.0, pinch and wheel zoom use fractional target zoom levels by default. Integer zoom level are only being enforced for +/- and drag zooming.

For drag zooming, it should now be easy to implement a `constrainResolution` option, but it has not been done. Creating a feature request ticket on https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers might help.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering I'm using 3.20.1 but my dragbox doesn't zoom in unless I select less than half the area.

Comment: @dibs487 I had misunderstood your question. Just updated the answer. You are right that drag zoom currently has no option to do unrestricted zooming.

Comment: this is the answer, its not the one I was looking for but it is right.  Thanks.